# Bind DataTable to Repeater control inside GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, eval, repeater

I have a grid view and repeater is inside a gridview in TemplateField.

I am binding a datatable to gridview. This datatable contains a column say **rptrDS** which contains datatable objects.

I need to bind these datatable objects to repeater's datasource property using Eval.

When I did this, error in coming like **Specified cast is not valid....**

This is fairly understood that I need to typecast the object returned from Eval into DataTable object. But I wonder if there is a way to do this. `Convert` class does not have any such function that says `ToDataTable()`

Second thing is only specifying DataSource value will not work out, I need to call DataBind as well. How to call DataBind in this scenario when DataSource itself is binded dynamically.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

place a gridview instead of eval. Then in your base gridview RowDataBound method, find that little gridview and give your table to it, bind there.

You may learn some tricks in here:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Nested-GridViews-GridView-inside-GridView-with-Expand-and-Collapse-feature.aspx